# Assign pandas.DataFrame column To Series with Default

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a `DataFrame`

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4]}, ['foo', 'bar'])

     a  b
foo  1  3
bar  2  4
```

And I want to added a column based on another `Series`:

```
s = pandas.Series({'foo': 10, 'baz': 20})

foo    10
baz    20
dtype: int64
```

**How do I assign the Series to a column of the DataFrame and provide a default value if the DataFrame index value is not in the Series index?**

I'm looking for something of the form:

```
df['c'] = s.withDefault(42)
```

Which would result in the following Dataframe:

```
     a b c 
foo  1 3 10
bar  2 4 42

#Note: bar got value 42 because it's not in s
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using `map` with `get`

`get` has an argument that you can use to specify the default value.

```
df.assign(c=df.index.map(lambda x: s.get(x, 42)))

     a  b   c
foo  1  3  10
bar  2  4  42
```

---

### Use `reindex` with `fill_value`

```
df.assign(c=s.reindex(df.index, fill_value=42))

     a  b   c
foo  1  3  10
bar  2  4  42
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) between `df` and dataframe which is obtained from `s` and then fill the `NaN` with default value, which is 42, in your case.

```
df['c'] = df.join(pandas.DataFrame(s, columns=['c']))['c'].fillna(42).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
foo 1   3   10
bar 2   4   42
```

Comment: won't this replace ALL nans with 42?  so nans in other columns will also be set to 42, which is not desired

Comment: `df.join(pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['c']))['c'].fillna(42)` will only fill the NaNs in the c col.

Comment: @kevinsa5, good point. I did not think beyond the minified example. Answer updated.